# Is it possible to make the \newcommand control sequence handle sweave code?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I use latex to write up homework assignments. I need to include both charts and R code with my assignment. Sweave has worked well for me so far, but I'd like to simplify common code blocks like this...

```
\begin{rcode}
<<label=sol1, include=FALSE>>=
plot(c(2,3,5,7,11))
@
\end{rcode}
\begin{figure}[H]
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
<<sol1>>
@
\end{figure}
```

(Where rcode is just a custom float...the code goes at end of document, the chart is stationary.)

So something like this...

```
\chart{sol1}{plot(c(2,3,4,5,7,11))}
```

where \chart is defined by

```
\newcommand{\chart}[2]{
  \begin{rcode}
  <<label=#1, include=FALSE>>=
  #2
  @
  \end{rcode}
  \begin{figure}[H]
  <<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
  <<#1>>
  @
  \end{figure}
}
```

Sadly, it appears that sweave gets to the source code before latex processes \newcommand, and so this approach doesn't work. Is there a way to tweak how the source is processed so that the macros are dealt with before sweave sees the source? Or is there a better approach to this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions..

Comment: No, but Sweave can create LaTeX control sequences, which solves this issue by coming at it from exactly the opposite direction.  That is, although you can't make R code from LaTeX, you can make LaTeX from R code.  See Dieter's solution for a nice example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following is about what you wanted to solve the hen/egg problem. I have stolen it from my own post on the R-list

```
% ---------------------------------- 
\documentclass{article} %
\usepackage{Sweave} 
\SweaveOpts{echo=FALSE}

\newcommand\bloodp[3]{
  \subsection{Patient #1} For patient #1, the mean value of systolic pressure was #2~mmHg, the diastolic pressure was #3~mmHg. 
  \begin{figure}[!htb]% 
    \begin{center}% 
      \includegraphics{histo#1}%
      \caption{Histogram of systolic blood pressure for patient #1.}% 
      \label{fig:histo#1}% 
    \end{center}% 
  \end{figure}% 
  \clearpage % Better use FloatBarrier here 
}

\begin{document} 
\section{Blood Pressure}

<<results=tex>>= 
n=100 
dt = data.frame(
   subj=sample(1:3,n,TRUE), 
   syst=round(rnorm(n,120,10)),
   dia=round(rnorm(n,80,10))
   )
# could also use tapply here 
for (i in 1:3) { 
  dt1 = dt[dt$subj==i,] 
  cat("\\bloodp{",i,"}{", 
     round(mean(dt1$syst)),"}{", 
     round(mean(dt1$dia)),"}\n",sep="") 
   pdf(paste("histo",i,".pdf",sep="")) 
   hist(dt1$syst,main="",xlab="Blood pressure") 
   dev.off() } 
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, this would work well if I had pre-compiled plots to include in the document. I've been making plots directly in latex, so I'm looking for something that's a little more on-the-fly...

Comment: @jessup: If you mean making plots in the R chunks of an Sweave file, that's what this post is doing; see the `hist` command.  The idea in this answer is really powerful; the idea is to make R commands that create the LaTeX commands you need and then call them from within R chunks.  Using this technique you can simplify your code in almost exactly the way you want to, except that the simplification in all within R chunks instead of all within LaTeX chunks.

Comment: Oh, yes. I was mistaken. This is a great approach. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script that seems to work well enough...I'm SURE there's somebody who can tell me how to do all of this with one line of PERL ;-) please let me know.

```
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{rcode}{b}{R}
\floatname{rcode}{R Code}

\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{rout}{b}{R}
\floatname{rout}{R Output}

\begin{document}

!@plot A very informative plot

a <- c(2,3,5,7)
plot(a)

@;

!@print Some output

a<-c(2,5,5,7)
print(a)

@;

\end{document}
```

Here's the python script, which I put in ~/Library/TexShop/Scripts/sweave_macros.py

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    old = open(sys.argv[1])
    new = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
    old_lines = old.readlines()
    i = 0

    out_file = ""

    while i < len(old_lines):

        if old_lines[i].lstrip()[0:2] == '!@':
            line = old_lines[i]
            obj = line[2:line.index(' ')].strip()
            label = line[line.index(' ')+1:line.index('\n')].strip()

            obj_end = i
            while old_lines[obj_end].strip() != "@;":
                obj_end += 1

            out_file += "\\begin{rcode}[p]\n"
            out_file += "<<label="+ label +", include=FALSE>>=\n"

            i += 1
            while i < obj_end:
                out_file += old_lines[i]
                i += 1

            out_file += "@\n"
            out_file += "\\caption{"+label+"}\n"
            out_file += "\\end{rcode}\n"

            if obj == "plot":
                out_file += "\\begin{figure}[H]\setkeys{Gin}{width=3.5in}\n"
                out_file += "<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=\n"
                out_file += "<<"+label+">>"
                out_file += "\n@\n"
                out_file += "\\caption{"+label+"}\n"
                out_file += "\\end{figure}"

            if obj == "print":
                out_file += "\\begin{rout}[H]\n"
                out_file += "<<echo=FALSE>>=\n"
                out_file += "<<"+label+">>"
                out_file += "\n@\n"
                out_file += "\\caption{"+label+"}\n"
                out_file += "\\end{rout}"
            i += 1

        else:
            out_file += old_lines[i]
            i += 1

    new.write(out_file)
    new.close()
```

Finally I updated the Sweave engine used by TexShop, locate in ~/Library/TexShop/Engines/Sweave.engine:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                               
export SWEAVE_STYLEPATH_DEFAULT="TRUE"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin
python ~/Library/TexShop/Scripts/sweave_macros.py "$1" "fin_$1"
R CMD Sweave "fin_$1"
pdflatex "fin_${1%.*}"
```

So now whenever I run the sweave engine from TexShop, the python script is called first, and it parses out text between the @! and @; delimiters in the way that you'd want.

I hope that this is useful to somebody...now to start on that homework....